# What are the marker enzymes for Nucleus, Ribosomes and cell membrane?

Tags: biochemistry, cell-biology, enzymes

Are there any marker enzymes present for ribosomes, nucleus and cell membrane. For mitochondria there are many, for lysosome it's cathepsin. I read about the marker enzymes of most of the other cellular components, but no information is there on these three.
If no marker enzymes are present then how are ribosomes, nucleus and cell membrane are identified.

I am specifically looking for marker enzymes which can help identify the pellet component after subcellular fractionation.

Comment: Why are specifically interested in marker enzymes? And could it be any enzymtically active proteins or are you looking for which activity can easily be measured? Ribosomes are catalytically active (ribo-)enzymes themselves and aren't actual compartments of the cell like all of the other things. The plasma membrane and nucleus are much more heterogeneous than mitochondria or lysosomes so they are usually identified by other markers than enzymes.

Comment: You need to describe the experimental procedure in which you need to check for these components. You can see nuclei and membranes under a microscope, and ribosomes are characterized by their components (look them up to see what these are), but I imagine that this may not be what you want. I suspect there is some incorrect premise underlying your question, but without the detail we cannot point it out.